# Memory leak in networkx.read_gml()?

Tags: python, graph, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, networkx

I'm trying to read a bunch of graphs (around 30k) from GML files and compute some properties of each graph using NetworkX library and its `read_gml()` function. Here is my code:

```
import os
import networkx as nx
folder = 'graphs/'
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    g = nx.read_gml(folder + filename)
    print g.number_of_nodes(), g.number_of_edges()
```

It seems that there is a memory leak in this function and it doesn't free the allocated memory after reading a file. Because it keeps consuming memory then my system freezes and crash (after processing around 15k files). 
I tried to add

```
del g
```

and

```
import gc
gc.collect()
```

but it didn't help. Any idea?

Comment: I can't reproduce the memory leak - this example https://gist.github.com/hagberg/7721279 maxes out at about 40MB for me.  Which version of networkx are you using?

Comment: I think the problem happens when Python reads a large graph from my graph folder. Actually it doesn't release the allocated memory even if the next graphs are small. I found [this article](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm) explaining why Python doesn't release the memory when a large object is deleted. To reproduce the memory leak try [this example](https://gist.github.com/accesstoken/7938508). It monitors the memory usage using [this code](https://gist.github.com/accesstoken/7938470).

Comment: I ran your code and it works fine for me - hovering around 250MB of memory used.  Do you see something different?  I'm using python2.7.3 and networkx_1.8dev versions.